# mongodb RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, mongodb

MongoDB version: 2.6.10, Node v6.12.1. , Ubuntu 16.04.3

I have a code that generates object in the MongoDB, the code works great when I run it locally (vagrant machine) , but when I run it on the AWS server it throws the following error - but only for the very specific scenario:

1. create an Outlet object,
2. create a Remote object associated to the Outlet ** ONLY for the first time**

NOTE:

1. The error is not throws if it's not the first time I create a Remote for the Outlet.
2. The Remote object is created in the DB but the Node process dies and restarts by Forever service (which cause the UI to break).

Log error message:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function.isValid (/data1/slmusic/mean/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/objectid.js:313:36)
    at new ObjectID (/data1/slmusic/mean/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/objectid.js:46:24)
    at clone (/data1/slmusic/mean/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:272:12)
    at cloneObject (/data1/slmusic/mean/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:343:13)
    at clone (/data1/slmusic/mean/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:260:16)
    at model.Document.$toObject (/data1/slmusic/mean/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2073:13)
    at model.Document.toJSON (/data1/slmusic/mean/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2364:15)
    at clone (/data1/slmusic/mean/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:252:18)
    at cloneArray (/data1/slmusic/mean/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:362:14)
    at clone (/data1/slmusic/mean/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:247:12)
    at cloneObject (/data1/slmusic/mean/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:343:13)
    at clone (/data1/slmusic/mean/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:260:16)
    at model.Document.$toObject (/data1/slmusic/mean/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2073:13)
    at model.Document.toJSON (/data1/slmusic/mean/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2364:15)
    at clone (/data1/slmusic/mean/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:252:18)
    at cloneObject (/data1/slmusic/mean/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:343:13)
```

Code:

Backend file for creating the Remote (relevant code in `create` method)

```
import * as Remote from "../models/Remote";
import * as Outlet from "../models/Outlet";
import * as Playlist from "../models/Playlist";
import * as Organization from "../models/Organization";


class RemoteRoutes {

   ....

    create(req: any, res: any, next: any) {
        Outlet.findById(req.body.oId, function (err: any, outlet: any) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            var remoteData = req.body;
            delete remoteData.oId;
            remoteData.outlet = outlet;
            Remote.create(remoteData, function (err: any, remote: any) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                }
                outlet.remotes.push(remote);
                outlet.save(function (err: any) {
                    res.json({
                        type: true,
                        data: remote,
                    });
                });
            });

        });
    }

    ...
}

var remoteRoute: RemoteRoutes = new RemoteRoutes();

export = remoteRoute;
```

Front end file for creating the Remote

```
define('js/controllers/addRemoteCtrl', [], function() {

  function addRemoteCtrl($scope, $routeParams, Remotes, Outlets, loginSrv, auth, $location, alertServ, loaderServ, validationServ) {
    // console.log('$routeParams ', $routeParams);
    auth.verify();
    $scope.outlet = Outlets.get({
      id: $routeParams.oId
    });


    function handleRequest(res) {
      if (res.type) {
        loaderServ.hide();

        $location.url('/remotes/' + $routeParams.oId);
      } else {
        // console.log('res.data ' , res.data);
        // alert(res.data);
        alertServ.add('danger', res.data);

      }
    }

    $scope.addRemote = function() {

      var remote = new Remotes({
        name: $scope.name,
        email: $scope.email,
        oId: $routeParams.oId,
      });

      if (validationServ.validateRemote(remote)) {
        loaderServ.show();
        remote.$save(handleRequest);
      }
    }


  };

  addRemoteCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Remotes', 'Outlets', 'loginSrv', 'auth', '$location', 'alertServ', 'loaderServ', 'validationServ'];


  return addRemoteCtrl;
});
```

Remote Schema IRemote.ts:

```
import IOutlet = require("./IOutlet");


interface IRemote {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    outlet: IOutlet;

};

export = IRemote;
```

Remote Schema Remote.ts:

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
import IRemote = require("./IRemote");




interface IRemoteModel extends IRemote, mongoose.Document { }

var remoteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    outlet: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Outlet' }

});

var remote = mongoose.model<IRemoteModel>("Remote", remoteSchema);

export = remote;
```

Comment: you might be having circular references

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to see how to avoid this, but why it fails only on the first attempt, only on the SRV?

Comment: Does this happen when you comment `outlet.save(...)` ?

Answer (score 0):

As Saravana mentioned, this is caused by circular references and can be solved as follows:

Use the following code to get the remotes (in RemotesCtrl.js):

```
$scope.getRemotes = function() {
  res = $http.get(API + '/outlet/remotes/' + $routeParams.id);
  res.then(function(res) {
    loaderServ.hide();

    $scope.remotes = res.data;
  });
  return res;
};

$scope.getRemotes();
```

and comment the following lines in remoteRoute.js

```
create(req: any, res: any, next: any) {
    Outlet.findById(req.body.oId, function (err: any, outlet: any) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        var remoteData = req.body;
        delete remoteData.oId;
        remoteData.outlet = outlet;
        Remote.create(remoteData, function (err: any, remote: any) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            // outlet.remotes.push(remote);
            // outlet.save(function (err: any) {
                res.json({
                    type: true,
                    data: remote,
                });
            // });
        });

    });
}
```

Here is the code of `getRemote()` in the backend:

```
  getRemotes(req: any, res: any, next: any) {
    Remote.find({outlet: req.params.id}, function (err: any, post: any) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        res.json(post);
    });
  }
```